# SQS: Age of newest message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events, aws-sqs-fifo

How can we calculate age of latest message in SQS?

**Use-case:** I want to trigger a notification based on time elapsed(Age) since the latest message landed on SQS queue. Say my threshold cutoff is 1 hour, if  first message lands on SQS at 11:00, second message lands on 11:50 and third message lands on 11:55. Then I want a notification triggered at 12:55.

SQS publishes ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage but I want something like Approximate age of newest message.

Comment: Amazon SQS does not provide the 'age of newest message'. See: [Available CloudWatch metrics for Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html)